# Struts2 dynamically add, remove list of objects from page

Tags: struts2

I am trying to build a page on Struts2 that adds values to a database table. The problem is, the page must allow users to input several rows to the database table. When user clicks submit, it must read and write rows to the database table. Users can add or remove rows from page

Therefore I tried to render List value on page. Java code looks like this:

```
List<Testimate> estimates;
private String removeIndex;

public String execute() throws Exception {
    estimates = new ArrayList<Testimate>();
    for(int i = 0; i < INITIAL_ESTIMATES; i++)
        estimates.add(new Testimate());
    return INPUT;
}
public String add() {
    estimates.add(new Testimate());
    System.out.println(estimates.size());
    return INPUT;
}

public String remove() {
    estimates.remove(Integer.parseInt(getRemoveIndex()));
    System.out.println(estimates.size() + " " + getRemoveIndex());


    return INPUT;
    }
```

> ```
> And the page looks something like this:
> ```

```
<script>
   setRemoveIndex()
   {    
        $('input[name="removeIndex"]').val(removeIndex);
        return true;
   }
</script>
<s:form theme="custom" onsubmit="setRemoveIndex()">
<s:submit action="CEST02_add" cssClass="ButtonSmall" value="Add estimate" />
<s:hidden name="removeIndex"/>
<table>
<s:iterator value="estimates" var="estimate" status="status">
<tr>
   <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].name"cssClass="product" /></td>
   <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].price"cssClass="product" /></td>
   <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].date"cssClass="product" /></td>
   <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].attr"cssClass="product" /></td>
   <td><s:submit action="CEST02_remove" cssClass="ButtonSmall" value="Remove this estimate" onclick="removeIndex=%{#status.index}"/>
   </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
</s:form>
```

And when I click "Add estimate" it adds element to the list "estimates". And it prints the size correctly. But when I click "Remove this estimate", it does not change the list "estimates". But it prints that the size of list is reduced by one. And when I click again, the size does not change at all. It does not get any modification.

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this code. I may have some huge misunderstanding how this framework works. If you have any questions or clarifications, please just ask

**UPDATE:**

I solved my issue with following lines on my JSP. But question still remains why I could not do this on my Action.

```
<s:iterator value="estimates" var="estimate" status="status">
   <s:if test="#status.index != removeIndex">
```

Comment: can you describe this a bit more `onclick="removeIndex=%{#status.index}"/`

Comment: In order to find out which submit was clicked, it saves the index number to a variable. Then it removes nth item from the list

Comment: have you tried this with debugger what exactly is happening?

Comment: I just debugged it, and I could not get something useful since there are not any source file for hibernate classes.

Comment: but as per your code its is not any where related to Hibernate not i can see such calls in your action class, and in that case hard to tell anything

Comment: Oh, don't worry about the database yet. It is on another method. I want to insert "estimates" to database when user clicks on another button called "Save". The only problem is I cannot remove item from "estimates" when I click "Remove this estimate".

Comment: That's really strange and for me this seems something odd.I still suspect the culprit as something association with ORM layer

Answer (score 3):

I tried with your code and its working fine for me.Though i do not understand the inner of your `Testimate` class so in place of `List<Testimate> estimates` i took `List<String> estimates;`.Here is my working code.

### Action Class

```
List<String> estimates;
private int removeIndex;
//there getters and setters

public String execute() throws Exception
    {

        estimates = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            estimates.add(""+i);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String remove() {
        estimates.remove(getRemoveIndex());
        System.out.println(estimates.size() + " " + getRemoveIndex());
        return SUCCESS;
        }
```

### JSP

```
<body>
  <script>
  function setRemoveIndex(val)
   {    
       alert(val);
       document.getElementById("removeIndex").value=val;
       //$('input[name="removeIndex"]').val(removeIndex);
       document.myform.action="remove.action";
       document.myform.submit();
        return true;
   }
</script>
<s:form theme="simple" id="myform" name="myform">
<s:submit action="CEST02_add" cssClass="ButtonSmall" value="Add estimate" />
<s:hidden name="removeIndex" id="removeIndex"/>
<table>
<s:iterator value="estimates" var="estimate" status="status">
<tr>
   <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}]"cssClass="product" /></td>
   <td>
   <s:submit action="remove" cssClass="ButtonSmall" value="Remove this estimate" onclick="return setRemoveIndex('%{#status.index}')"/>
   </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
</s:form>
</body>
```

### Struts.xml

```
 <action name="remove" class="example.HelloWorld" method="remove">
     <result>/example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

This above code is perfectly deleting the List values and i have checked with page refreshing also and values are not getting back.

Comment: Thank you @Umesh Awasthi. My Testimate class is model class that was generated by Hibernate. My code look exactly same, except the list type is <Testimate>. Do you think that would cause a problem?

Comment: @batbaatar i don't thik if you POJO/Model is detached from hibernate else it could create issues for sure

Comment: I don't know how it is attached to hibernate that much except the mapping to the database table. The model only implements Serializable interface. Can you explain me why would hibernate create issues?

Comment: that's my initial guess if they are independent of the ORM layer than it should not be an issue else changing Object state can cause hibernate to update its object state but still i am not sure it can be a case.while you deleting the values have you seen any log message related to ORM layer??

Comment: Does not show anything with log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG. I think it has some business with interceptor which does populating. But I could not find which one

Comment: Interceptor?? i am not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: @batbaatar i even tried with your same use case except that there is no ORM in action and create a `POJO` namely `Testimate` with a property `name` and its working fine for me

Comment: Then I guess, it was ORM issue. But I still need to know if issue was in my code or usage of ORM. Have you found any official source mention about this issue?

Comment: no not found anything like that.A suggestion just for testing stop ORM interaction and fill your `POJO/Model` in you r action class (hard coding) and than see how its behaving

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried flushing your Hibernate session in remove() after you remove the item? I think your changes are not being commited.

Comment: Hi, I am not doing any database operation when I am removing it. I just want to remove it from the list so user can reduce the number of row on page

Comment: Set a breakpoint on execute() and check if your INPUT action is directing to it. Is you remove action set up as:

    <action name="remove" class="example.HelloWorld" method="remove">
        <result>/example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>

Comment: As I mentioned above, it printed the size of list and index I wanted to remove

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code which works for me as expected:

**Action Class**

```
package com.mycompany;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class EstimateAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Testimate> estimates;
    private String removeIndex;
    private static final int INITIAL_ESTIMATES = 10;

    public List<Testimate> getEstimates() {
        return estimates;
    }

    public void setEstimates(List<Testimate> estimates) {
        this.estimates = estimates;
    }

    public String getRemoveIndex() {
        return removeIndex;
    }

    public void setRemoveIndex(String removeIndex) {
        this.removeIndex = removeIndex;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        estimates = new ArrayList<Testimate>();
        for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_ESTIMATES; i++) {
            estimates.add(new Testimate());
        }
        return INPUT;
    }

    public String add() {
        estimates.add(new Testimate());
        System.out.println(estimates.size());
        return INPUT;
    }

    public String remove() {
        estimates.remove(Integer.parseInt(getRemoveIndex()));
        System.out.println(estimates.size() + " " + getRemoveIndex());


        return INPUT;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="showEstimates" class="com.mycompany.EstimateAction">
            <result name="input">/estimatePage.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="removeEstimates" class="com.mycompany.EstimateAction" method="remove">
            <result name="input">/estimatePage.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**estimatePage.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setRemoveIndex(removeIndex)
            {
                document.myForm.action = "removeEstimates.action";    //First set the form to navigate to the specific action
                $('input[name="removeIndex"]').val(removeIndex);
                //alert("Here");
                document.myForm.submit();                             //Submit the form with the action attribute change
                return false;                                         //Cancel the form submission which was triggered earlier
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:form name="myForm" onsubmit="setRemoveIndex()">
            <s:submit action="add" cssClass="ButtonSmall" value="Add estimate" />
            <s:hidden name="removeIndex"/>
            <table>
                <s:iterator value="estimates" var="estimate" status="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].name"cssClass="product" /></td>
                        <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].price"cssClass="product" /></td>
                        <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].date"cssClass="product" /></td>
                        <td><s:textfield name="estimates[%{#status.index}].attr"cssClass="product" /></td>
                        <td><s:submit action="remove" cssClass="ButtonSmall" value="Remove this estimate" onclick="return setRemoveIndex(%{#status.index})"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </table>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```