# Insert Multiple Object using struts 2.0

Tags: java, struts2

I want to store one to many mapping for eg. A purchase order contain multiple item .i want to show a page to end user where he can insert multiple item and after submission action class should have purchase order object which have collection of objects

i want to know how we can implement this in struts .

i want to know what  tag should be used in jsp page .

Answer (score 0):

you can use same name for all the items and struts will map them to an array in the action

in jsp

```
<s:textfield name="a" id="a" />
<s:textfield name="a" id="b" />
<s:textfield name="a" id="c" />
<s:textfield name="a" id="d" />
```

in action you can define an array to hold these value like String []a;

Comment: Thanks can i use collection to store these value and i also want to enable that user can add as may as value as he want using add button this dose need not server call .

Comment: what do you mean by collection i.e. collection inside another object?

Comment: I did something similar here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906910/struts2-dynamically-add-remove-list-of-objects-from-page